# Can the relationship between Gibbs (free) energy change to Equilibrium constant of a chemical reaction be derived from Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics

Can the relation between Gibbs(free) energy change to Equilibrium constant of a chemical reaction be derived from the  Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution only ? ( Theoretically , with may be an empirical and conceptual background explanation may also be granted . )

i.e. The equation which is : ${\Delta_\text{r} G}^o=-RT\ln K_\text{eq}$

Comment: Yes, but with some restrictions such as on the number of atoms/molecules and their total energy which enables partition functions to be calculated and from these the classical thermodynamic functions G, H, S can be found. Books on Statistical Mechanics give the calculation to find partition functions.

Comment: @porphyrin please describe a bit

Comment: First you need to find out about partition functions. Most phys chem textbooks cover this. Then look for the connection between these and normal thermodynamic properties.